# regular expression help: catch this: |TrxId=475665|

Tags: regex

For example I have a string:

```
MsgNam=WMS.WEATXT|VersionsNr=0|TrxId=475665|MndNr=0257|Werk=0000|WeaNr=0171581054|WepNr=|WeaTxtTyp=110|SpraNam=ru|WeaTxtNr=2|WeaTxtTxt=100 111|
```

and I want to catch this: `|TrxId=475665|`

after `TrxId=` it could be any numbers and any amount of them, so regex should catch as well:

`|TrxId=111333|` and `|TrxId=0000011112222|` and `|TrxId=123|`

Comment: Which language are you doing this in? There might be an easier/better way than a regex.

Comment: @JamWaffles I don't think there is a better way, you can split and loop over the array but I don't think that would be a huge speed increase since this regex is kinda O(n) where n is the string length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TrxId=(\d+)`

That would give a group (1) with the TrxId.

PS: Use global modifier.

Answer (score 3):

The regex should look somewhat like this:

```
TrxId=[0-9]+
```

It will match `TrxId=` followed by at least one digit.

Answer (score 1):

An example solution in Python:

```
In [107]: data = 'MsgNam=WMS.WEATXT|VersionsNr=0|TrxId=475665|MndNr=0257|Werk=0000|WeaNr=0171581054|WepNr=|WeaTxtTyp=110|SpraNam=ru|WeaTxtNr=2|WeaTxtTxt=100 111|'

In [108]: m = re.search(r'\|TrxId=(\d+)\|', data)

In [109]: m.group(0)
Out[109]: '|TrxId=475665|'

In [110]: m.group(1)
Out[110]: '475665'
```

Answer (score 0):

You know what your delimiters look like, so you don't need a regex, you need to `split`. Here's an implementation in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = "MsgNam=WMS.WEATXT|VersionsNr=0|TrxId=475665|MndNr=0257|Werk=0000|WeaNr=0171581054|WepNr=|WeaTxtTyp=110|SpraNam=ru|WeaTxtNr=2|WeaTxtTxt=100 111|";

my @first_array = split(/\|/,$input); #splitting $input on "|"

#Now, since the last character of $input is "|", the last element
#of this array is undef (ie the Perl equivalent of null)
#So, filter that out.

@first_array = grep{defined}@first_array;

#Also filter out elements that do not have an equals sign appearing.

@first_array = grep{/=/}@first_array;

#Now, put these elements into an associative array:

my %assoc_array;

foreach(@first_array)
{
  if(/^([^=]+)=(.+)$/)
  {
    $assoc_array{$1} = $2;
  }
  else
  {
    #Something weird may be happening...
    #we may have an element starting with "=" for example. 
    #Do what you want: throw a warning, die, silently move on, etc.
  }
}

if(exists $assoc_array{TrxId})
{
  print "|TrxId=" . $assoc_array{TrxId} . "|\n";
}
else
{
  print "Sorry, TrxId not found!\n";
}
```

The code above yields the expected output:

```
|TrxId=475665|
```

Now, obviously this is more complex than some of the other answers, but it's also a bit more robust in that it allows you to search for more keys as well.

This approach does have a potential issue if your keys appear more than once. In that case, it's easy enough to modify the code above to collect an [array reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) of values for each key.

Answer (score 0):

```
/MsgNam\=.*?\|(TrxId\=\d+)\|.*/
```

for example in perl:

```
$a = "MsgNam=WMS.WEATXT|VersionsNr=0|TrxId=475665|MndNr=0257|Werk=0000|WeaNr=0171581054|WepNr=|WeaTxtTyp=110|SpraNam=ru|WeaTxtNr=2|WeaTxtTxt=100111|";
$a =~ /MsgNam\=.*?\|(TrxId\=\d+)\|.*/;
print $1;
```

will print TrxId=475665

Comment: `.*` is not required! it should be `(TrxId\=\d+)` only

Comment: i usually prefer to keep some side decorations if it is possible (f.e. it is not code under high load systems for optimizations). Just a matter of taste